# loading custom dataset for training in wav2vec2

Tags: python, speech-to-text

Im trying to finetune wav2vec2 for a custom dataset which has two columns `path` and `transcription`. `path` contains the location to the wav file. I'm getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2699, in training_step
> loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 2731, in compute_loss
> outputs = model(**inputs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/wav2vec2/modeling_wav2vec2.py", line 1684, in forward
> outputs = self.wav2vec2(
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/wav2vec2/modeling_wav2vec2.py", line 1306, in forward
> extract_features = self.feature_extractor(input_values)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/wav2vec2/modeling_wav2vec2.py", line 433, in forward
> hidden_states = input_values[:, None]
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Here is the rest of the code:

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer, Wav2Vec2Processor
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
import pandas as pd
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer, Wav2Vec2Processor
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torchaudio
import warnings

# Filter and suppress all warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

tokenizer = Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base")
processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base")
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base")


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, tokenizer, processor):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)[['path', 'transcription']]
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.processor = processor

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        audio_path = self.data.iloc[idx]['path']
        transcription = self.data.iloc[idx]['transcription']

        # Load and process the audio file
        waveform, _ = torchaudio.load(audio_path)
        input_values = self.processor(waveform, return_tensors="pt").input_values
        attention_mask = torch.ones_like(input_values)

        # Tokenize the transcription
        labels = self.tokenizer(transcription, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

        return {"input_values": input_values, "attention_mask": attention_mask, "labels": labels}


# Load the custom dataset
train_dataset = CustomDataset('train_data.csv', tokenizer, processor)

# Define the TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./wav2vec2-finetuned",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    save_steps=500,
    save_total_limit=2,
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    logging_dir="./logs",
    logging_steps=100,
    logging_first_step=True,
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
)

# Define the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    data_collator=lambda data: {
        "input_values": [item["input_values"] for item in data],
        "attention_mask": [item["attention_mask"] for item in data],
        "labels": [item["labels"] for item in data],
    },
)

# Start training
trainer.train()
```